# Range over string slice in golang template

Tags: go, go-templates

I have a struct that contains a slice of type string like the following.

```
 type Data struct {
      DataFields []string
 }
```

Within my html template file I would like to range over the string slice. However, the individual fields are just strings without any struct name. How can I loop over a slice that contains a simple type such as string, int, etc?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Or assign it to a variable, similar to a normal Go range clause:

```
 {{range $element := .DataFields}} {{$element}} {{end}}
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Use8Za8vwey)

From the [docs for text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) (serves as interface docs for html/template):

> ```
> {{range pipeline}} T1 {{end}}
>     The value of the pipeline must be an array, slice, map, or channel.
>     If the value of the pipeline has length zero, nothing is output;
>     otherwise, dot is set to the successive elements of the array,
>     slice, or map and T1 is executed. If the value is a map and the
>     keys are of basic type with a defined order ("comparable"), the
>     elements will be visited in sorted key order.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> A pipeline inside an action may initialize a variable to capture the result. The initialization has syntax
>
> `$variable := pipeline`
>
> ...
>
> If a "range" action initializes a variable, the variable is set to the successive elements of the iteration. Also, a "range" may declare two variables, separated by a comma:
>
> `range $index, $element := pipeline`
>
> in which case $index and $element are set to the successive values of the array/slice index or map key and element, respectively. **Note that if there is only one variable, it is assigned the element; this is opposite to the convention in Go range clauses.**
>
> (bold portions emphasized by me)

Answer (score 38):

Use `.` to refer to a simple values like a string, int, etc.

```
 {{range .DataFields}}{{.}}{{end}}
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ITnFGRXAKI9).

You can also assign to a template variable as in `{{range $v := .DataFields}}{{$v}}{{end}}`, but that's extra work.  Embrace the `.`.

Comment: Personally, the second syntax, `{{range $v := .DataFields}}{{$v}}{{end}}` provides a significant benefit in readability for a few more characters on the screen. I'll take that tradeoff!